# Make sure one out of two fields of class is defined

Tags: typescript

Lets start with type, I have type

```
type myType = {
  requiredProperty : string; 
  optionalProperty? : string; 
  anotherOptionalProperty? string; 
}
```

If i want to make new type that ensures that at least one property from `optionalProperty` and `anotherOptionalProperty` is defined I can for example use [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) `RequireAtLeastOne`

and do

```
type myNewType = RequireAtLeastOne<myType, 'optionalProperty' | 'anotherOptionalProperty' >
```

and everthing works fine. Now lets consider similar case but with class

```
 class myClass {
   requiredProperty : string; 
   optionalProperty? : string; 
   anotherOptionalProperty? string; 
 }
```

How can i achieve same functionality i.e. how should i modify code of class to be sure that at least one from `optionalProperty` , `anotherOptionalProperty` is there.

Comment: You can't have a class implement a union.  The easiest and cleanest solution is to just make the class have a union-typed property instead of making the class *be* the union.  Otherwise you will need to do things like a class hierarchy (which is tedious), or a generic class (which will require explicit `undefined`s instead of optionality).  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nr975w) for options. Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?